# Comparing 2 strings from HTML file - Angular

Tags: html, angular, date

I am using angular 7 and I would like to know how to compare two `strings`. In this case, each of my `strings` simulates one `date`, let's say "2019-12-26" and "2018-12-26".

In `Javascript` is pretty simple to compare them since I just need to use the operators:

```
console.log(today > "2018-12-06");
```

It is working how I supposed it was gonna work. It basically returns `true`. Nevertheless, I am trying to do exactly the same from my HTML file

```
 <div *ngIf="today > example.endDate">
```

being `today` and 'example.endDate' two `strings` containing exactly the same `strings` that I used for the `Javascript` example, but it does not show any of them.

Is there any other way to make this comparison?

Regards,
Mario

**UPDATE**
I have had a second look at the problem and it seems that the comparison is not a problem, but the way of getting the variable is.

I get a variable in `ngOnInit()`.

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.getCurrentDate();
  }

  //Get current date
  getCurrentDate() {
    let aux = new Date();
    //2 characteres
    let dd = String(aux.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    let mm = String(aux.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); //January is 0!
    let yyyy = aux.getFullYear();
    let today = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    let other = "2019-01-31";
  }
```

The problem is that I use this variable directly in my `HTML` how I previously showed. The error I get is the following:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: undefined'.
>   Current value: 'ngIf: true'.

So the problem is that I am using a variable in the `HTML` file before getting the `value`. Or at least it is what I understand

To check this error I have created a `Stackblitz` representation. On it, I have created two examples:

1. Variables not on `ngOnInit()`
2. Variables in `ngOnInit()`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjgsmq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: it seems to be working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zd6d6j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. share your demo code

Comment: Yes, I have tried exactly that and it works. It seems that my problem is that I am using a variable that I get on init. I am gonna try to explain it better updating the question. I'd appreciate if you could have a look :)

Comment: It seems that the other is declared as a local variable using let and it is not a component variable

Comment: I think the solution is to render the view after getting the value but i am not sure about how to do it

Comment: From @ShashankVivek stackblitz, it seems to work fine even when I change other date later.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sk9atk
Could you reproduce your problem on stackblitz

Comment: I have updated again the question :) Of course, my data does not work on the same way but it more or less show my error

Comment: Sorry now the link is the good one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the most simple solution is just to 
and are you sure that ngOnInit is the right LifeCycle hook for you?
I would try ngAfterContentInit() if the component is "heavy" to render other wise ngAfterViewInit() would have been my choice

```
<div *ngIf="IsTodayBigger()">

    ngOnInit() {
    this.getCurrentDate();
  }

 IsTodayBigger(): boolean {
    today=this.getCurrentDate()
    exampleEndDate= example.endDate;//use binding or ViewChild if needed
  return today&&exampleEndDate&& today> example.endDate
  }

  //Get current date
  getCurrentDate() {
    let aux = new Date();
    //2 characteres
    let dd = String(aux.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    let mm = String(aux.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); //January is 0!
    let yyyy = aux.getFullYear();
    today = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    let other = "2019-01-31";
  }
```

Comment: Do not know if it is the best practice but it actually works. Thanks :)